# Linux Device Driver - How to unblock reading thread when closing file?

Tags: linux, io, driver, device, blocking

I am attempting to implement a character device driver for Linux and am having trouble. In short, data written to the device is buffered for reading. When no data is available, the call to read blocks via 'wait_event_interruptible'. Data received by the write handler calls 'wake_up_interruptible'. The release handler also calls 'wake_up_interruptible' to unblock the reader but sets a flag to indicate the driver is releasing.

From user space I have an executable that opens the driver via 'open' and then starts another thread. The main thread proceeds to call 'read'. As intended, no data is available for reading and the call blocks. The other thread sleeps for one second (providing sufficient time for the main thread to read and block), calls 'close' and then calls 'close' again. The first call returns '0' while the second returns '-1' (as expected). However, my driver's release handler is never called and I cannot understand how to unblock my reading thread without explicitly sending it a signal or writing some data to the device. My understanding is that when the last handle to the driver closes that its release handler is invoked. I am trying to implement what I believe is standard user space behavior- a thread blocked reading from a file will become unblocked and receive an end-of-file return value when asynchronously closed.

Do I have the correct understanding of read/close at the file level in user space? Do I have the correct device driver understanding? Am I missing something else? I looked through 'Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition' and couldn't quite find an answer to this question. I have also searched Google but cannot seem to find the answer either. Any help you can provide is appreciated. My kernel version is 3.0.15.

Comment: I would look into the sockets code for inspiration. I *think* that closing a socket handle makes and reads and recvs on the socket return 0.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the read syscall keeps a reference on the file itself and not the file descriptor. So closing the file descriptor will not abort the read.

In all cases you must be careful about races conditions between unblocking and closing, you don't want the thread (or another one) to re-enter the syscall between ;)